# Doesn't delegate type act like other reference types when assigning happens?

Tags: c#, delegates, reference-type

Why doesn't the following code behave as the other reference types in the very situation which is when we assign a ref object to another ref object, both objects will point to the same location in the memory? It look likes a copy by value happened here to me.

`delegate` declaration:

```
class Car {
   public delegate void CarEngineHandler(string text); 
   /* ... */
}

Car.CarEngineHandler carHandler1 = PrintText1;
carHandler1 += PrintText2;

Car.CarEngineHandler carHandler2 = carHandler1;
carHandler2 -= PrintText2;
carHandler1("Hello");
```

The output:

> Printing from PrintText1: Hello
>   Printing from PrintText2: Hello

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegates are immutable, so when you run e.g. this line (which calls [`Delegate.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.delegate.remove)):

```
carHandler2 -= PrintText2;
```

you create a *new* delegate and store it in `carHandler2` *instead* of changing the existing one.

---

To illustrate this more, take a look at the following code, which uses strings (strings are also a reference types and immutable):

```
String string1 = "Foo";
string1 += "Bar";
String string2 = string1;
string2 += "EvenMorebar";
```

`string2` is now `FooBarEvenMorebar`, but `string1` is still `FooBar`.